# Why is R returning an error that my variable must be an integer if the variable already is an integer?

Tags: r, integer

I am attempting to run a multi-level regression and  poststratification in R, and I keep getting an error that my dependent variable "must be integer values of 0 / 1 or logical". I ran the following

```
punitive.data <- within(punitive.data, punall <- as.integer(punall))
```

followed by

```
is.integer(punitive.data$punall)
```

which returned a response of `TRUE`.

Then I ran

```
mrp.simple <- mrp(punall ~ statenum + f.race , data = punitive.data, population = census.data)
```

which returned the following error:

```
Error in checkResponse(response, response.varname) : 
'punall' must be integer values of 0 / 1 or logical.
```

I rechecked the variable type with the `is.integer` function and got a `TRUE` response again. The variable also shows as an integer in the Environment. All values in the variable are either 0 or 1.

Any advice or help would be greatly appreciate.

Comment: If this is a question about data types, a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) is going to be necessary to give meaningful help. Are you *sure* that that variable only has values of 0 or 1? Because your error message says it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it by doing the following

```
punitive.data$punall <- as.logical(punitive.data$punall)
```

And then this should work

```
 mrp.simple <- mrp(punall ~ statenum + f.race , data = punitive.data, population = census.data)
```

Note that if your data contains a value higher than 1 it will become `TRUE`.

Comment: Hi, dylanvanw. I tried this as well, and I keep getting the same error in response.

Comment: That is unfortunate. I will need a reproducible example in that case to help you further just as @camille said.